# how to do looping and calculation to find distance of multiple trips in spark scala dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

my dataframe looks like this 
[image]

here what i want

1. whenever the first occurrence of value in column -- " location2_distance_from_lat_long"  is  <= 1.0 km ,

it will start calculating the distance/(fetch the timestamp value) until it reaches to the first occurrence of value in other column i.e "location2_distance_from_lat_long" which is <=100

likewise loop continues for second occurrence

e.g
at timestamp 1529321201000 ,the value of column "location2_distance_frm_lat_long" is 1km , the it will start the trip calculation.
and suppose at timestamp 155352242000 in other column "location1_distance_frm_lat_long" the value is also reaches to 1km then upto that point , need to fetch all the records and calculate the distance.
and again next trip will start after that timestamp.

```
  code
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHRZW.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

in above if how do i write looping for when distance reaches to <=.100km

Comment: can't see the dataframe...

Comment: also include what you have tried so far to solve your problem (nice nickname by the way...)

Comment: @antonioACR1 hi jst chk it wat i tried.hope to have a positive response